# Drupal 8: file_move() in validate formular generate a "Recoverable fatal error"

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

Despite I folow this [tutorial](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example%21form_example_tutorial.inc/function/form_example_tutorial_10_validate/7.x-1.x), my drupal 8 generate a "Recoverable fatal error"

There is the message of Drupal log: "Recoverable fatal error : Argument 1 passed to file_move() must implement interface Drupal\file\FileInterface, array given, called in.."

Here my code:

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

   $file = file_save_upload('file', array(
    // Validates file is really an image.
    'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
    // Validate extensions.
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg'),
  ));
  // If the file passed validation:
  if ($file) {
    // Move the file into the Drupal file system.
    if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://')) {
      // Save the file for use in the submit handler.
      $form_state['storage']['file'] = $file;
    }
    else {a
      form_set_error('file', t("Impossible d'enregistrer correctement le fichier."));
    }
  }
  else {
    form_set_error('file', t("Aucun fichier n'a été téléchargé."));
  }
  }
```

Is this a "right" problem?
This is the basic code for upload a file.

I have added all dependencies. And more..

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;
use Drupal\eshpubmanager\Mutuals\ESHPubManagerMutuals;
use Drupal\eshpubmanager\Calendar\ESHPubManagerCalendar;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
use Drupal\Core\Routing;
use Drupal\Core\Url; 
use Drupal\file\FileInterface;

use Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandlerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface;
use Drupal\Core\State\StateInterface;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
use Drupal\stream_wrapper_example\StreamWrapper\SessionWrapper;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
```

Somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, `file_save_upload` will return an array if multiple files are uploaded. In the error message it says that `file_move` was passed an array so you might be uploading multiple files or perhaps your file input element has the `multiple` attribute set.

Confirm this in your form build. If you want to have a single file upload and you have `multiple` flag remove it. If your goal is to upload multiple files you have to loop through the values returned by `file_save_upload` and perform `file_move` on each of them.